# Equations of Motion for Hidden Photon

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, maxwell-equations, variational-calculus

I was reading a paper called [Parametrically enhanced hidden photon search](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4806) by Peter Graham *et al*. In the paper, a Lagrangian that describes the theory of the hidden photon is
$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}(F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+F'_{\mu\nu}F'^{\mu\nu})+\frac{1}{2}m_{\gamma'}^2A'_\mu A'^{\mu}-eJ_{EM}^\mu(A_{\mu}+\varepsilon A'_\mu).$$

The paper says in a following section that this Lagrangian leads to equations of motion:

$$\begin{align}(\partial_t^2+\nabla^2)V&=\rho_{EM}\tag{1}\\
(\partial_t^2+\nabla^2)\vec{A}&=\vec{J}_{EM}\tag{2}\\
\dot{V}+\nabla\cdot \vec{A}&=0\tag{3}\\
(\partial_t^2+\nabla^2+m_{\gamma'}^2)V'&=\varepsilon\rho_{EM}\tag{4}\\
(\partial_t^2+\nabla^2+m_{\gamma'}^2)\vec{A}'&=\varepsilon\vec{J}_{EM}\tag{5}\\
\dot{V}'+\nabla\cdot \vec{A}'&=0\tag{6}
\end{align}$$

My question is how to get these equations of motion from that Lagrangian. I tried using the Euler-Lagrange Equation. Using $A^{\nu}$  gives the inhomogeneous Maxwell's equations. I'm to use $A'^{\nu}$ now. I think it gives some modified Maxwell's equations, but I still can't quite get to these equations.

Comment: I formatted your post to be a bit more readable. Now, how on earth do equations (3) and (6) even make sense? You're adding a vector with a scalar??

Comment: @ArturodonJuan I think that's just a typo in the paper. $V$ and $V'$ are a scalars and so shouldn't have arrows. Also (this time trusting the paper) (3) and (6) have time derivatives on $V$ and $V'$.